# ReactJs how to import component from sibling folder inside src folder?

Tags: reactjs, import

```
/src
|--components
|  |--Layout
|  |  |--AppLayout.js
|  |  |--Header.js
|  |  |--Content.js
|  |  |--Footer.js
|  |--Root.js
|--constants
|  |-- AppConfig.js
|--index.js
```

Currently, I have my react js project structured as described above. My question is how can I import config from AppConfig.js in the file Root.js(sibling folder inside src folder), and also import it to the AppLayout.js? I have tried `import APPCONFIG from '../../constants/appConfig';`, `import APPCONFIG from '../constants/appConfig';`, `import APPCONFIG from './constants/appConfig';`, `import APPCONFIG from './constants/appConfig';` and `import APPCONFIG from 'constants/appConfig';` but nothing works.

Comment: `'../constants/appConfig'` looks to be the correct relative path for importing into `Root.js`, and `'../../constants/appConfig'` for the other. How is `APPCONFIG` exported from that file though? What, if any, error are you receiving?

Comment: Nothing matched the filename. It's `AppConfig` not `appConfig`.

Comment: Ah, agreed with @BhojendraRauniyar, voting to close due to typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based on how you export class/function AppConfig

1. Say your class/function name is AppConfig and you export it like

const AppConfig = () => {}
export default AppConfig;

You can import AppConfig below way.

```
1. For Root.js

import AppConfig from '../constants/AppConfig';

2. For AppLayout.js

import AppConfig from '../../constants/AppConfig';
```

2. Say your class/function name is AppConfig and you export it like

export const AppConfig = () => {};

You can import AppConfig below way.

```
1. For Root.js

import {AppConfig} from '../constants/AppConfig';

2. For AppLayout.js

import {AppConfig} from '../../constants/AppConfig';
```

If still not work then please provide way you export your AppConfig class/function

more details related export and import class/function es6 javascript please check below links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 0):

from Applayout.js  you want to import Appconfig.js

so in Applayout.js
`import  APPCONFIG from '../../constants/AppConfig`

## Some Tips for you

- read more about root import
- use editors that gives you some functionalities to help you in this small cases